# Get text from a HTML web document .NET

Tags: html, vb.net, text, web, document

Basically what I want to do is get text from a HTML web document,

```
<a href="showthread.php?tid=2632829">1</a> 
<a href="showthread.php?tid=2342818">1</a> 
<a href="showthread.php?tid=2342818">1</a> 
<a href="showthread.php?tid=2342818">1</a> 
....
....
```

All these link are in different lines and a lot of other scripts in between them.
right now the  catch is I want to search for "`1</a>`" in these documents and get the link

```
showthread.php?tid=11digitnumber
```

I then want to place them in a richtextbox line by line
say

```
    showthread.php?tid=11digitnumber
    showthread.php?tid=11digitnumber
    showthread.php?tid=11digitnumber

...
```

What I have done so far is got the source of webpage using

```
source = WebBrowser1.DocumentText.ToString()
```

Earlier I had some luck using

```
dim ss,variable as string

variable = ss.Substring(ss.LastIndexOfAny(">1</a> ") - 27, 27)
output:
showthread.php?tid=11digitnumber
```

but I am only able to use this once,besides there are many such files in the document

Comment: are you using a webbrowser because you need to display the process to a user, or because you dont know any other ways of getting a webpages source code?

Answer (score 1):

you just have to play with a bit of logic like:

```
myOriginPoint = your starting point (usually 0)

myLastOccurrence = your last point (usually with LastIndexOf)
```

then you can use a loop and a temporal list like:

```
List<String> urls = new List<String>();

while(myOriginPoint < myLastOccurrence )
{

    //retrieve the keyword
    var urlFound = your logic to retrieve the url

    //save the keyword 
    urls.Add(urlFound);

    //move to next position 

    myOriginPoint = indexOf  +1;

}
```

By the way, you can also use WebClient in .Net, si much better to retrieve data from a url: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx

I hope it helps,